# Scrapy: use a different .cfg file

Tags: python, scrapy

By default Scrapy uses scrapy.cfg in the projects root. 
Is there a way to tell it to use a different .cfg file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is the default behavior.See [this](http://dev.scrapy.org/browser/scrapy/utils/conf.py) source.

Answer (score 0):

As v01d said there's no way to explicitly tell scrapy to use a scrapy.cfg wherever you want it to be in the directory tree but if you look at the implementation of closest_scrapy_cfg - https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/utils/conf.py#L24 - you can move scrapy.cfg up any level to root and it will find it.

So for example, if your default scrapy.cfg is:

/home/whatever/scrapy-projects/abc/scrapy.cfg

you can move it up one or more level.

Not sure where's the advantage though.